# Universal module definition IIFE pattern

Tags: javascript

How does the following code work? How can a function invoke a function from an expression that hasn't been reached by the compiler yet? `def(window)` is reached before `(function def(...)` is reached. Where am I going wrong in thinking about this? Thank you.

```
var a = 2;

(function IIFE( def ){
def( window );
})(function def( global ){
var a = 3;
console.log( a ); // 3
console.log( global.a ); // 2
});
```

Comment: `def(window)` is not reached before the `def` function is reached. With IIFE's the second set of parenthesis (the one's not enclosing the function) are the parameters. The function `def` is being parsed as a parameter to the `IIFE` function before the `IIFE` function is invoked. So the `IIFE` function is parsed (not invoked), the `def` function parameter is parsed (not invoked), the `def` function parameter is passed to the `IIFE` function (which is now being invoked) and the `def(window)` statement is executed (invoking the `def` function). At least that's my understanding of how this works.

Comment: Arguments are *always evaluated first* and the result is passed to the function. So here, `function def( global ){...}` is an argument passed to the function which accesses the argument via `def`.

Answer (score 0):

"`def(window) is reached before (function def(...)`"
. This is not true. `def` is an argument to `IIFE` therefore `def` gets executed with window as it's parameter and you get the proper results. Nothing unusual in JavaScript.

It helps if you separate out the functions:

```
var a = 2;

function def(global) {
  var a = 3;
  console.log(a); // 3
  console.log(global.a); // 2
};

function IIFE(def){
    def(window);
}

IIFE(def);
```

**http://jsbin.com/jomep/1/edit**

Answer (score 0):

This code is a little more verbose than I'd have coded it.  Namely, the `IIFE` function is named even though it is being executed in an anonymous way.  The same is also true of the `def` function-- it's used anonymously even though it has a name.

Anyway, to answer your question: the `IIFE` function is created as you would any other function in Javascript.  But then it is immediately executed with a parameter, which is perfectly valid in Javascript.  The parameter is another function.  Just like any other language, the parameter is evaluated at the function call site.  JavaScript, however, also treats functions as data.  In this example, the function `def` is defined at the call site, then fed into the `IIFE` function's parameter list.

Edit: [Moog's reformatted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25627221/425533) certainly helps clarify it, too!